# How to use iBeacon in ionic2 app?

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, ecmascript-6, ibeacon, ionic2

I am new to `ionic framework`, with that `AngularJS`. I have started learning and developing in `Ionic framework` using `Ionic ver2` (which is using `AngularJS2`).

I would like to know, how to use **external libraries in Ionic2**?  Like using `cordova iBeacon`, [cordova iBeacon docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/beacon/).

How to structure my app so that I can write one or more generic functionality using external libs (*like cordov iBeacon*) and use it in my app where ever I needed (*Like in different pages js*).

OR - how can I include libraries required to do native hardware related actions?

Feel free to give all your thoughts and suggestions regarding this.

Many many thanks.

Comment: Please do share if you have any article or docs related to this topic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally I was able to figure out all by myself.

> **Step 1: Add plugin into the app**

By moving into project folder through the command line, run the following line of command to add the plugin into project

**`sudo cordova plugin add https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon.git`**

> **Step 2: Using the plugin in the app**

make sure in `plugins/fetch.json` plugin details are added:

```
"com.unarin.cordova.beacon": {
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/petermetz/cordova-plugin-ibeacon.git",
            "subdir": "."
        },
        "is_top_level": true,
        "variables": {}
    }
```

And in `plugins/android.json` in `installed_plugins` following lines are there,

```
"com.unarin.cordova.beacon": {
            "PACKAGE_NAME": "io.ionic.starter"
        }
```

That's it, we start using the plugin features in any pages, in the app, by using the variable : **`cordova.plugins.locationManager`**

> Example use cases:

To enable device bluetooth : **`cordova.plugins.locationManager.enableBluetooth();`**

> **NOTE**
>   If it is not working fine, update the plugin again. To update the `cordova-plugin-ibeacon` I first **`removed`** the plugin from the app and **`added again`**.

Comment: Happy to know that somebody came across this. Welcome. :)

Comment: Yes but how to import in ionic-native? `import {cordovaBeacon} from 'ionic-native';` is it possible this way?

Comment: `export class UserPage {`

Comment: @peter.swallow `cordova` is undefined?

Comment: is cordova still a global variable in Ionic2 or do we need to import it somehow?

Comment: I never imported it manually. I think until we don't change any config files it will be available. Please check with a new app generated via ionic2.

Comment: @peter.swallow may be you are running in the emulator which is not able to run cordova

Answer (score -2):

```
export class UserPage {constructor(authservice, navcontroller) {
        this.service = authservice;
        this.nav = navcontroller;
        this.distance = 0;    
   }
   getDistance(){
        delegate.didRangeBeaconsInRegion = function (pluginResult) {
              this.distance=pluginResult.beacons[0].rssi;
        };
   }
}
```